# Проблема с  Zend Framework: не подключается класс Zend_Form

Tags: framework, php, zend-framework

На днях решил освоить  Zend Framework нашел скринкаст http://vimeo.com/12704093,
установил, но не могу понять, почему не подключается класс Zend_Form!

Не могу создать форму.

```
// скрипт из файла UsersController

class UsersController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
      $this->view->title= 'Список пользователей.';
      $this->view->headTitle($this->view->title,'PREPEND');
    }

    public function addAction()
    {
      $this->view->title= 'Добавить нового пользователя.';
      $this->view->headTitle($this->view->title,'PREPEND');

      //здесь он не находит класс Form_User()
      $form =  new Form_User();

      $this->view->form = $form;
    }

    public function deleteAction()
    {

    }

    public function viewAction()
    {
      $this->view->title= 'Просмотр данных пользователя.';
      $this->view->headTitle($this->view->title,'PREPEND');
    }

    public function editAction()
    {
      $this->view->title= 'Редактировать данные пользователя.';
      $this->view->headTitle($this->view->title,'PREPEND');
    }
}

// скрипт из файла User

class Form_User extends Zend_Form
{
    public function _construct()
    {
        $this->setName('form_user');
        parent::__construct();

        $username = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('username');        
        $password = new Zend_Form_Element_Password('password');        
        $email = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('email');        
        $submit = new Zend_Form_Element_submit('submit');        
        $this->addElements(array($username,$password,$email,$submit));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Класс своей формы нужно назвать `Application_Form_User`. Тогда ZF будет искать его в "application/forms/User.php".

**UPD:** И инициализировать форму не в конструкторе а в методе `init()`

```
class Application_Form_User extends Zend_Form
{
    public function init()
    {
        $this->setName('form_user');
        $username = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('username');        
        $password = new Zend_Form_Element_Password('password');        
        $email = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('email');        
        $submit = new Zend_Form_Element_submit('submit');        
        $this->addElements(array($username,$password,$email,$submit));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вместо $form =  new Form_User();
попробуй использовать полную запись.
$form = new Application_Form_User();